# Deactivate wpa_cli notifications

Tags: wpa-supplicant, notifications, wpa, wpa-cli, messaging

Is it possible to deactivate `wpa_cli` notifications/messages like `<3>WPS_AP_AVAILABLE`? Because it spams it, and in a VT where you have to slowly type MACs@ and bssIDs, it's really hard with those bothering messages

Comment: Is `wpa_cli` message overwriting your terminal input?

Comment: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no. [This](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/wpa_cli.c#n104) function is responsible for deciding if events sent from `wpa_supplicant` to `wpa_cli` are written to the interactive terminal.

```
static int wpa_cli_show_event(const char *event)
{
    const char *start;

    start = os_strchr(event, '>');
    if (start == NULL)
        return 1;

    start++;
    /*
     * Skip BSS added/removed events since they can be relatively frequent
     * and are likely of not much use for an interactive user.
     */
    if (str_starts(start, WPA_EVENT_BSS_ADDED) ||
        str_starts(start, WPA_EVENT_BSS_REMOVED))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

The only events that are not written are `WPA_EVENT_BSS_ADDED` and `WPA_EVENT_BSS_REMOVED` (which is good because they can happen hundreds of times when a scan is executed). Fastest way to stop this message from printing in your interactive terminal would be to modify the `if` statement to

```
...
    if (str_starts(start, WPA_EVENT_BSS_ADDED)    ||
        str_starts(start, WPA_EVENT_BSS_REMOVED)  ||
        str_starts(start, WPS_EVENT_AP_AVAILABLE))
...
```

You could also add in any other messages you find annoying - the macros are defined [here](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/src/common/wpa_ctrl.h).

Comment: It would be a nice thing to suggest an option for that to the devs, but otherwise I will compile this correction myself effectively, thanks